# Error saying "CompletableFuture(Object) has private access in CompletableFuture" when implementing CompletableFuture

Tags: intellij-idea, java-8, completable-future

I am implementing `CompletableFuture` as below but getting an error saying

> `CompletableFuture(Object)` has private access in `CompletableFuture`

```
public CompletableFuture<A> init(B b) {

    C c = new C();  
    CompletableFuture<A> future = new CompletableFuture<A>(c);

    return future;
}

public class C implements Callable<A> {

    public A call() throws Exception {
        A a = new A();
        return a;
    }
}
```

I hope solution to overcome this error?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: Which part of “CompletableFuture(Object) has private access” don’t you understand? `private` means that constructor is not meant to be used by other classes. This includes your class. Besides the access issue, what makes you think, you can pass a `Callable` to that constructor and get a useful behavior? Are you mixing up `CompletableFuture` and `FutureTask`?

Comment: @Holger - I have successfully implemented `FutureTask` and now trying to implement `CompletableFuture` because I want to work asynchronously.

Comment: What’s stopping you from using `FutureTask` asynchronously?

Comment: We do not have control of the future when it completes. But in `ComletableFuture` we can call .complete whenever we need to submit it. Just google about the best suite.

Comment: Since you said “I have successfully implemented `FutureTask`”, that doesn’t make any sense. You can control the completion of a `FutureTask`, when you have implemented it yourself. If you haven’t implemented it, contrary to what you said, then the executor will control it, but that’s not different to using `supplyAsync`, where the completion is determined by the framework.

Comment: Please check the difference between `FutureTask` and `CompletableFuture`. Then you will see we have better control from `CompletableFuture` when we are working on asynchronous mode.

Comment: @Holger `CompletableFuture` will be use full when you have external dependencies to current thread. As example if you are looking for a response from a server to complete task. And also there are some better control over `FutureTask` in `CompletableFuture`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no public constructor in `CompletableFuture` class which accepts a parameter. It's better to use [`CompletableFuture.supplyAsync()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#supplyAsync-java.util.function.Supplier-) static method which takes a `Supplier` instead of `Callable`:

```
CompletableFuture<A> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(A::new);
```

Or using lambda:

```
CompletableFuture<A> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> new A());
```

Note that if `A` constructor throws checked exception, you should handle it as `Supplier` interface does not support exceptions:

```
CompletableFuture<A> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    try { return new A(); }
    catch(Exception ex) { throw new RuntimeException(ex);}
});
```

Finally note that `supplyAsync` will not only create the `CompletableFuture`, but also schedule it for execution in common thread pool. You can specify custom `Executor` as second parameter to `supplyAsync` method. If you want to create `CompletableFuture` without sending it imediately for execution, then probably you don't need a `CompletableFuture`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I may have miss understood the concept. I have one question further. Is that mean, there is no need of a class which has extend from `Callable`?. In my code that is the point where do a time consuming task. According to your explanation the task should be done in `try catch` block? If then where should I `complete` the future?

Comment: @Malinda, yes, in try-catch block. You may create new class (implementing `Supplier`, not `Callable`), but for simple functions it's easier to write lambda instead. To complete the future, just return the value from the lambda (or `Supplier.get` method in case if you create new class).

Comment: I implemented this successfully. Thank you for the help.